# BadTokenException when launching a dialog in asyncronous thread

Tags: android, dialog

I have an activity that makes an asynchronous connection, like this:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                //Make Connection
            }catch(Exception e){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { 
                     Dialogs.showErrorDialog(MyActivity.this); //I display an error dialog using this context
                } });
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Imagine that the connection is really slow, and I leaved the activity that launched this thread. If the connection finally goes well, everything is fine, but if the connection fails, it crashes when launching the dialog, as the context does no longer exist. The error is:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@4068a558 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

How to avoid this error? I would like to detect if my activity is still alive to either

1) show a dialog with this context (if I'm still on the screen)

2) show a Toast with ApplicationContext (if I'm outside the screen)

EDITED:
The dialog code is this:

```
static public void showErrorDialog(Context context){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.error_title);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.error_content);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok,null);
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: as the exception says: Is MainActivity running or do you call the finish() on its instance?

Comment: Thats the issue. The activity is finished, but I still want to show an error dialog to the user when the thread is done

Comment: yoy can not do this. You can use the context of another activity in order to draw the dialog but not the context of a finishing activity

Answer (score 2):

> How to avoid this error?

I suggest you to use this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
   public void run() { 
      if (!(((Activity) context).isFinishing())) { // you need to pass Context.
         Dialogs.showErrorDialog(context);      
      }
   } 
});
```

Let me know if it works.

**Note:** If it won't works, i recommend to you use `AsyncTask` instead of `runOnUiThread()`.

Answer (score 0):

can't change UI in thread; you use RunOnUiThread, but the UiThread still in the thread.
You can use AsyncTask to do it.

```
class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //Make Connection
        boolean flag = connecting(); //flag is connect state: success or fail
        return flag;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (!result) {
            Dialogs.showErrorDialog(MyActivity.this); 
        }
    }

}
```

then, use as follows:

```
ConnectionTask task = new ConnectionTask();
task.execute();
```

Comment: Still not working, as the Dialog launches with a Context that don't exist anymore.

Comment: please paste the Dialogs.showErrorDialog code, let us know the content

Comment: try this:                                                             static public void showErrorDialog(Activity context){
    
}                                                                            change the Context to Activity